# Animate from top not working with negative value?

Tags: javascript, animation

**EDIT**

Solved it. See post below.

**/ END OF EDIT**

**EDIT**

NOT related to the suggested topic above and not solved by changing to `vh` as measurement of top-value instead as shown in this fiddle (as suggested by the first comments here): http://jsfiddle.net/wm02ovx8/3/. The div still doesn't animate in, but rather pops up in the blink of an eye.

**/ END OF EDIT**

I'm trying to animate a drawer div from top and into view. The animation works fine as long as it's in view to begin with (the "top" css property value being more than -1), but since I have a negative value that is `calc(-100% + 30px)` on the `top` property it just "pops up" instead. What am I missing here?

[[Fiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/wm02ovx8/2/) *(To open the menu, press the index word on the right)*

**HTML:**

```
<div id="closeIndexLayer"></div>
<div id="alignLinks">
    <div id="anchorLinks"></div>
</div>

<div id="indexMenu">Index</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#alignLinks {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-flow: wrap;
    left: 30px;
    top: calc(-100% + 30px);
    background: rgba(255,0,0,.60);
    /* transform: translateX(-50%); */
    height: calc(100% - 30px);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
    z-index: 250 !important;
    min-width: 425px;
    max-width: 425px;
    box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0,0,0,0.30), 0 15px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}

div#anchorLinks {
    display: flex;
    /* position: fixed; */
    flex-flow: wrap;
    height: auto;
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* background: rgba(0,0,0,.5); */
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 250;
}

div#closeIndexLayer {
    position: fixed;
    display:none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    z-index: 250;
}

a.anchorLink {
    width: auto;
    background: hsla(210, 11%, 8%, 1);
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    -webkit-transition: all 140ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 140ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 140ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 140ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 140ms ease-in-out;
}

#indexMenu {
        position: fixed;
        display: block;
        z-index: 249;
        top: 50%;
        height: 18px;
        right: -18px;
        padding: 0px 6px 0px 6px;
        transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(270deg);
        background: rgba(255,255,255,.15);
        border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
        font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,.12), 0px 2px 3px rgba(255,255,255,.24);
    cursor: pointer;
    }
```

**Javascript:**

```
function showIndex() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("alignLinks");
    thestyle = window.getComputedStyle(elem),
    thetop = thestyle.getPropertyValue('top');

    var pos = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
    function frame() {
        if (pos <= 0) {
            pos++;
            elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
        } else {
            clearInterval(id);
        }
    }
}

function hideIndex() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("alignLinks");
    thestyle = window.getComputedStyle(elem),
        thetop = thestyle.getPropertyValue('top');

    var pos = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
    function frame() {
        if (pos >= 0) {
            pos--;
            elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
        } else {
            clearInterval(id);
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById("indexMenu").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var closeIndexLayer = document.getElementById("closeIndexLayer");

    closeIndexLayer.style.display = "block";
    showIndex();
});

document.getElementById("closeIndexLayer").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var closeIndexLayer = document.getElementById("closeIndexLayer");

    closeIndexLayer.style.display = "none";
    hideIndex();
});
//</editor-fold>
```

Comment: @A.Meshu I'm not sure I follow why it's related..

Comment: @A.Meshu I really think you misunderstood the root of my problem. -100vh didn't change anything. check updated example.

Comment: you right and i'm apologize... (:

Comment: @A.Meshu solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it another way instead, and in a way I'm more familiar with. The way I found that worked for me adds a class to the element and that class have animation properties. Then if you want to animate out, just add the animation properties to the element that is being animated (in this case the id `#alignLinks`).

[[Fiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/wm02ovx8/5/)

Javascript:

```
let drawer = document.getElementById("alignLinks");


document.getElementById('indexMenu').onclick = function() {
  if(this.innerHTML === 'Index') 
  { 
    this.innerHTML = 'Close';
    drawer.classList.add('topAnimDown');
  } else {
    this.innerHTML = 'Index';
        var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(drawer),
    topProp = computedStyle.getPropertyValue('top');
    drawer.style.topProp = topProp;
    drawer.classList.remove('topAnimDown');
  }  
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="closeIndexLayer"></div>
<div id="alignLinks">
    <div id="anchorLinks"></div>
</div>

<div id="indexMenu">Index</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  background: hotpink;
}

div#alignLinks {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-flow: wrap;
    left: 30px;
    top: calc(-100% + 30px);
    background: rgba(255,0,0,.60);
    /* transform: translateX(-50%); */
    height: calc(100% - 30px);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
    z-index: 250 !important;
    min-width: 425px;
    max-width: 425px;
    box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0,0,0,0.30), 0 15px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    -webkit-transition: 3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 3s ease-in-out;
  transition: 3s ease-in-out;
}

.topAnimDown {
  -webkit-transition: 3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 3s ease-in-out;
  transition: 3s ease-in-out;
  top: 0 !important;
}

div#anchorLinks {
    display: flex;
    /* position: fixed; */
    flex-flow: wrap;
    height: auto;
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* background: rgba(0,0,0,.5); */
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 250;
}

div#closeIndexLayer {
    position: fixed;
    display:none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    z-index: 250;
}

a.anchorLink {
    width: auto;
    background: hsla(210, 11%, 8%, 1);
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    -webkit-transition: all 140ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 140ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 140ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 140ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 140ms ease-in-out;
}

#indexMenu {
        position: fixed;
        display: block;
        z-index: 249;
        top: 50%;
        height: 18px;
        right: -18px;
        padding: 0px 6px 0px 6px;
        transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(270deg);
        background: rgba(255,255,255,.15);
        border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
        font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 24px;
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,.12), 0px 2px 3px rgba(255,255,255,.24);
    cursor: pointer;
    }
```